# is there any way to add git to embarcadero xe5?

Tags: git, delphi, delphi-xe5, c++builder-xe5

I try to add the git to my embarcadero xe5 but i m getting hard time.

Please knowing that there is a git version for xe8, i need to know if it is possible to add git to my xe5 or no ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that git integration was added to Delphi with version XE7. The third party VersionInsightPlus project might be able to help, but it has been abandoned. Your best hope is to do some websearch for VersionInsightPlus, and try to install it yourself, possibly from source.

Answer (score 0):

Git is not integrated into the IDE in Delphi XE5. I would recommend [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) as a third-party git client. It doesn't integrate into the IDE, but it's nice and easy to use and can do Mercurial too.

Answer (score 0):

XE was the first version that had version control support in the ToolsAPI. So any version after that should be able to provide git support (XE7 just added it out of the box).
VersionInsightPlus contains Git support (I am using it on Delphi XE at work though I prefer using SourceTree 1.5.2).

Get the code yourself and build it for your Delphi version: http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudioverins/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/